# Filename as a variable in the Jupyter notebook

Tags: variables, jupyter-notebook, filenames

Let's say I have two variables

```
name='apple'
sentence='apple is delicious.'
```

in a cell.
Then I write

```
with open('name.txt', 'a') as fp:
    fp.write(sentence)
```

Then, jupyter notebook produces a text file named 'name.txt' with the sentence.
But I want to produce a text file named 'apple.txt' so that everytime I change the value of the variable 'name', I would get txt files with different filenames.

What could I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
with open(name+'.txt', 'a') as fp:
        fp.write(sentence)
```

Comment: That's what i want.